# Why did the Vorlons work with the Minbari?

Tags: babylon-5

Why did the Vorlons and Minbari start working together? The Vorlons seem to mess with and influence many younger races to set up their galactic chess game with the Shadows, but then worked with the Minbari to design the White Stars.

What elevated the Minbari from pawns to... minions I guess?

Comment: Everyone needs a pet.

Comment: Won't have a definite answer without some sort of history of the Minbari, but they're a very orderly people.  Rigid honor, caste systems, clans, crystal buildings... They're like Vorlon catnip.

Comment: The Minbari having fought the previous Shadow War and being the most advanced of the younger races probably have something to do with it.

Comment: The Mimbari had close to 1000 years to learn from the Vorlon technology left over from the previous Shadow War. The White Stars might not have had any Vorlon input.

Comment: Valen is why. He first appeared to the Minbari in the company of two Vorlons and got the races to work together against the Shadows.

Comment: Because this doesn't constitute a proper answer, I'll just say it here: the Minbari are to the Vorlons as the Drakh are to the Shadows. Both sides had pawns that they use directly, and dozens they use indirectly. And @PatrickWynne is right, but he needs to [flesh it out](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Valen) and I don't want to steal his glory.

Comment: The question would be more pointed if it had stuck to the metaphor and asked what elevated them from pawns to bishops, knights, and rooks.

Comment: The Minbari are also closest to the Vorlons tech level.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The Minbari had fought the Shadows in the last war, and the Vorlons accompanied Valen

In the first Shadow War (1000 years prior to the show), the Minbari were the primary force fighting the Shadows. When Valen first met the Minbari (the events of which we see in the episode *[War Without End, Part II](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/War_Without_End,_Part_II)*), he was accompanied by two Vorlons, who appear as angelic beings (you can see their encounter suits beside Valen).

[image: Valen with Vorlons]

The Vorlons' primary goal is to oppose the Shadows. The fact that the Minbari did so during the previous war, and their greatest leader was accompanied by Vorlons*, meant that they continued to be allies. We see that Delenn is one of the first to advocate for defeating the Shadows and is working with Kosh to do so.

Additionally, the Minbari very much support a rigid caste system and society. The Vorlons believe that Order is the right way to guide society (rather than Chaos as the Shadows believe), so a society that continues a strong tradition of Order is someone who will likely trust the Vorlons in their plans.

---

* It seems that the Minbari are one of the only races where at least some people know what a Vorlon really looks like, given that Dukhat and later Delenn had seen a Vorlon.

Comment: Which episode is that screenshot from?

Comment: @DanielRoseman War Without End II

Comment: On the footnote, Delenn kinda already peeked at the end of Season 1, in *Chrysalis*.  That's why she knows.  Before her, apparently only Dukhat had laid eyes on them.

Comment: @Radhil Thanks, I've corrected that.